# how to make sense of expression logic in ssis

Tags: regex, ssis, bids, sql-data-tools

I am working on a SSIS project that involves unzipping a folder which when extracted contains multiple text files in the same directory using a ForEachLoop Container.
each file will have a different Name.

**I have two variables of which variable 2 has an expression**

```
Variable 1
name = zipfileName 
Value= sample.zip

variable 2
name = FileName 
value = *.* 
Expression = REPLACE(@[User::ZipFileName],".zip",".txt")
```

I need clarification concerning the expression part

My thinking is that this expression means the name of the zipfile is replaced with .txt extension when extracted? I also would like to know how it dynamically changes fileNames in runtime seeing as there
are multiple files

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `Expression` is replacing `.zip` for `.txt` in `[User::ZipFileName]`

If the value of `[User::ZipFileName]` is `somefile.zip`

the output would be:

```
somefile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks  Pedro    , Do you have any idea how it caters for picking a different file name every time since there are multiple files to run through?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood well your comment, `[User::ZipFileName]` seems to be a variable, so, it should change on every interaction.

Comment: what I mean is lets say I have 3 of these text files as in abc.txt , def.txt and ghi.txt. The files will contain two columns ClientID and FileName e.g abc.txt .My question  is how do I retrieve the filename part for each interaction and place it in the DB?